# C# MVC ASP.NET URL parameter in HTTP GET unencoded improperly

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api

So I'm doing a GET to my fancy new WebAPI, and one of my parameters is a URL that I escape using encodeURIComponent.  In fiddler, the request looks like

```
GET /api/myapi/myurl/https%3A%2F%2Ft.co%2FkIEnlT8Mvn HTTP/1.1
```

so that's good.

However, if I look at the request in my Application_BeginRequest, I get

```
?HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath 
"/api/myapi/myurl/https:/t.co/kIEnlT8Mvn"

?HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
"http://localhost:23652/api/myapi/myurl/https:/t.co/kIEnlT8Mvn" 

?HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.OriginalString
"http://localhost:23652/api/myapi/myurl/https:/t.co/kIEnlT8Mvn"

?Request.RawUrl
"/api/myapi/myurl/https:/t.co/kIEnlT8Mvn"
```

So my question is:  How can I get the correct URL out of what is sent from the client?  I want to get either

A good URL https:SlashSlasht.co/kIEnlT8Mvn (the // changed because SO hates short URLs)

or

https%3A%2F%2Ft.co%2FkIEnlT8Mvn

not https:/t.co/kIEnlT8Mvn

(I've also tried encoding the URL with escape() and encodeURL(), with the same results.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slash is a separator between URL parts, and it looks something inside .NET or MVC or the Routing system is acting strict about this by removing the repeated slash. I don't know if that can be solved or changed.

I think it will work if you can change both the API & the call you are making to use a querystring parameter, something like this:

`GET /api/myapi/myurl?address=https%3A%2F%2Ft.co%2FkIEnlT8Mvn HTTP/1.1`

```
public ActionResult MyUrl(string address)
{
    // do your magic here...
}
```

Comment: yea, that makes sense.  I've added code to my existing handler to fixup the URLs I'm getting, but your solution would probably be better.  I may just change my whole way of doing it though, because I want it to work with as little goofing around as possible.